# The name "NAME" does not exist in the namespace: xaml issue in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I'm pretty new to visual studio and am building a simple WPF app that queries some data from an external database and graphs it on the screen. I found several graphing toolkits for WPF apps (DynamicDataDisplay, MetroChart, and LiveCharts). However, for all of them, I receive the following error when getting started:

"The name "NAME" does not exist in the namespace "NAMESPACE OF TOOLKIT""

For example, with MetroChart, I have the following

```
xmlns:chart="clr-namespace:De.TorstenMandelkow.MetroChart;assembly=De.TorstenMandelkow.MetroChart"
```

in my window declaration but when I try to use the resource:

```
<chart:PieChart />
```

I get the above error with the line underlined in blue.

I have added the correct dll as a reference and have also attempted to fix the issue by "unlocking" the dll and restarting both Visual Studio and my machine.

**In addition, my code builds and runs fine, but the error means that I can't work with my xaml in the designer due to invalid markup.**

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Does everything compile, and run, even with the blue underline showing in the code?

Comment: Yup, it compiles and runs fine but I am unable to use the designer at all due to the code being interpreted as an Invalid Markup.

Comment: Got it. Who needs the designer when you can code the XAML by hand!? :) Good luck!

Comment: Can you post an actual error message? Exactly as it appears.